# How to remove overlapping of softkeyboard with edittext while entering the edittext in listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I am having the edittext in listview. When entering some field in edittext using softkeyboard it is overlapping the edittext. I am using the below coding in manifest file..

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan"

But this is not working..

Comment: does softkeyboard overlap edittext or other edittext overlap with each other ?

Comment: if i click last edtittext means it ll overlap last 2 or 3 edittext.

Answer (score 0):

```
InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
  Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If edittext of list item over lap with each other then it's item's layout problem.

If softkeyboard over lap with edittext and you want to solve it then use **scrollview** as in your list item's layout. Cause `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan"`
only display the current focusing status of the edittext while you write, not the full edit text status.

Comment: The listview itself taking the default function of scroll view.. Then why should i adding scroll view in listview?